# org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at

Tags: java, spring, solr, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-solr

I have a spring application and I am using Solr to save documents. I am using spring data solr to communicate with Solr cores. Initially I had Solr setup on my local, hence in the application.properties file I had written `spring.data.solr.host=http://localhost:8983/solr`. But now I have deployed Solr on Google Cloud Platform and when I tried connecting the solr instance on GCP by changing above configuration to `spring.data.solr.host=http://ip-address-of-the-solr-instance/solr`. It is giving me `401 unauthorized` Below is the stack trace of my spring boot application

```
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
; nested exception is 
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: 
Error from server at http://ip-address-of-gcp-instance/solr: Expected mime type 
application/octet-stream but got text/html. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
] with root cause

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: 
Error from server at http://ip-address-of-gcp-instance/solr: Expected mime type 
application/octet-stream but got text/html. <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You should provide your application properties and spring application annotations.